# axios vue js - cross-origin request blocked the same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

i'm new learn vue js, i want to send data API from vue JS to Backend Laravel.
Data already sent to backend and already saved to database. But when i'm check console after send parameter, then vue js redirect to **catch** not **response**.

And this error in console => **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:2000/register/store. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).**

[image]

I don't know, why parameter has been received in backend and success, but vue js not redirect to **response**. So it doesn't display alert message :(

**This respond from backend laravel :**

```
{"message":"Success!","status":"200","value":"{\"nama\":\"test\",\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"123\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-05-07T05:50:41.000000Z\",\"created_at\":\"2020-05-07T05:50:41.000000Z\",\"id\":48}"}
```

**And this my code**

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
        <img alt="Vue logo" style="width:100px;height:100px" src="./assets/logo.png"><br/><br/>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Sign Up Form</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Let's join our web today.</h6>
                        <div v-if="loading == true">
                            <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form v-else v-on:submit="submitSignUp" class="text-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputFullname">Full name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFullname" v-model="fullnameForm" placeholder="Enter Full name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" v-model="emailForm" placeholder="Enter email">
                                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="passwordForm" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
      name: 'app',
      data() {
        return {
          responseAPI: '',
          loading: false,
          fullnameForm: '',
          emailForm: '',
          passwordForm: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        submitSignUp(params) {
          this.loading = true;
          var optionAxios = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
          }
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('name', this.fullnameForm);
          formData.append('email', this.emailForm);
          formData.append('password', this.passwordForm);
          axios.post('http://localhost:2000/register/store',formData,optionAxios)
            .then(response => {
              this.responseAPI = response;
              //why not display this alert
              if(response.status == 200) {
                alert('form success');
              } else {
                alert('form failed');
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
              this.errored = error;
            })
            .finally(() => {
              this.loading = false
              this.fullnameForm = '',
              this.passwordForm = '',
              this.emailForm = ''
              })
            params.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: try getting a browser extenstion CORS and then turn on "enable cors"

Comment: in backend laravel ?

Comment: no on your browser where you are running your code. You are violating the protocols so you need to disable the CORS.

Comment: Thank's i found this website to enable cors > https://enable-cors.org/server.html
i'm try enable cors in laravel